# opentok interconnect with node js express

Tags: node.js, opentok

I am implementing opentok interconnect with nodejs express.
 Getting **error**:

> No callback given to dial, while implementing dial-out.

My use case is as per documentation.

I am able to get all required values like ***config, sessionId, token, auth.*** , but still unable to connect the call.

```
    opentok.dial(sessionId, token, config.uri, options, {  
   auth: {      
 username: config.uname, password: config.pass     } 
}, 
   function (err, sipCall) {  
    if (err) 
      return res.status(500).send('Platform error starting SIP Call:'+err); 
      res.send(sipCall);   
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are posting too many arguments into the function before the callback.
From the [github repo](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-node#working-with-sip-interconnect) we can see the example:

`opentok.dial(sessionId, token, sipUri, options, function (error, sipCall) {`
We can see the arguments:

1. sessionId
2. token
3. sipUri
4. options
5. callback

You however are passing in an object between options and the callback.

```
opentok.dial(sessionId, token, config.uri, options,
// Extra object argument, is this meant to be options?
{
auth: {
    username: config.uname, password: config.pass}
},     
function (err, sipCall) {
    if (err) 
        return res.status(500).send('Platform error starting SIP 
Call:'+err); 
    res.send(sipCall);
 });
```